# PHP-FPM rm Permission denied

Tags: shell, nginx, permissions, php

I have nginx+php-fpm and I need to delete folder recursively from php-script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
$out = shell_exec('/bin/rm -vrf /data/vmail/test');
var_dump($out);
```

$out is NULL, but in error.log i receive

```
WARNING: [pool www] child 7210 said into stderr: "rm: "
WARNING: [pool www] child 7210 said into stderr: "cannot remove `/data/vmail/test'"
WARNING: [pool www] child 7210 said into stderr: ": Permission denied"
```

- PHP-FPM runs under user "nginx"
- NGINX runs under user "nginx"
- /data/vmail and all child folders are owned by vmail:vmail (chmod 770)

Supplementary groups exists:

```
# groups nginx
nginx : nginx vmail
# groups vmail
vmail : vmail nginx
```

### Solutions

- If I chown `/data/vmail/test` to nginx:nginx it **contents** becomes deleteable. But `/data/vmail/test` still is not, as long as `/data/vmail` is owned by vmail:vmail I suppose.
- If I `chmod -R 777 /data/vmail/test && chmod 777 /data/vmail` the meant folder becomes deleteable.
- PHP-function `rmdir()` works (don't know why)! But recursive deletion for large folders is too resource-intensive

I don't consider these options as a solution. Also I don't consider a solution involving root user and `/etc/sudoers` or running php-fpm as a root. So... how is it possible to get /bin/rm working?

### Additional info ##

- [php-fpm.conf](http://pastebin.com/52TFRFh0)
- [nginx.conf](http://pastebin.com/mL0nBHL5)

Comment: did you alter group ownerships after starting php-fpm? in case of...

Answer (score 1):

Deleting content of a directory is a write operation in The directory. So the user that runs PHP needs write permission on /data/vmail.